# Do I need to package a MySQL server/client with my pyinstaller app?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyside, pyinstaller

I built an application using pyside and sqlalchemy.  I package this application with Pyinstaller.  It works great with the sqlite database engine, but I am starting to deploy it now and want to do so with the mysql engine.  Do I need to package a Mysql server/client with the application?  And if so can I do so with Pysinstaller?

Comment: No `Pyinstaller` is just for python packages, if you want to install other softwares like `MySQL`, then you need to do that with software installation programs. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software) is a list of [them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers).

Comment: Thanks, if you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) are only use for python scripts, that just converts your python script and their's 3rd-party packages into stand-alone executable program without requiring a python installation.

If you want to install other softwares like `MySQL`, then you need to do that with software installation programs.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software) is a list of [them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers).

Comment: So the steps are: 1. Make the py files 2. Make executable using pyinstaller 3. Make the setup that imports mysql server if needed.